# Automated 7zip task - "can not open file as archve"

Tags: php, 7zip

I have an automated task that listens for a 7zip file to be received from a remote machine, and then extracts the archive. The process runs fine whenever I manually push the file from the remote machine. However, at a certain time of day several dozen machines are pushing files to my server, and about 8-9% of the files return the following error when 7zip tries to extract them:

```
7-Zip (A) [64] 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18
p7zip Version 9.20 (locale=en_US.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,6 CPUs)

Processing archive: /home/pos/inbox/05730049_20140206.7z

Error: Can not open file as archive
```

When I go in later to extract them manually, there is no problem unzipping the archive:

```
7-Zip (A) [64] 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18
p7zip Version 9.20 (locale=en_US.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,6 CPUs)

Processing archive: /data/pos/processed/05730013_20140206.7z

Extracting  file01.txt
Extracting  file02.txt
Extracting  file03.txt
Extracting  file04.txt
Extracting  file05.txt
Extracting  file06.txt
Extracting  file07.txt
Extracting  file08.txt
Extracting  file09.txt
Extracting  file10.txt

Everything is Ok

Files: 10
Size:       472129
Compressed: 16506
```

I'm pretty sure there is nothing wrong with the archive because (1) the script is the same on each remote machine and it only happens with 8-9% of the archives, and (2) when I extract it manually, it doesn't return the same error. Is there any way to make sure the file extracts properly on it's own?

The php code that extracts it is this:

```
function import_unzip($filename) {
  global $debug,$fail_type,$clientID,$location,$mode;

  ...

  if (!is_readable("/home/pos/inbox/$filename")) {
    $fail_type = 'NF';
    return false;
  } else {    
    //Unzip the file
    $cmd_res = exec("7za e -y -o/data/pos/$clientID$location /home/pos/inbox/$filename -p{$zip_passwd[$clientID]}",$output,$return_var);
    return $success;
  }
}
```

My first inclination is to put an error handling while loop around the 7z command and give it three or so tries, but I'm hoping there's a more elegant solution.

Comment: Guessing here, the file is "not ready" yet, i.e. it is readable, but not yet contains all the content? also ur code looks dangerous, you might be allowing attackers to insert content into the command line, where does $clientID, $location, $filename, $zip_passwd coming from?

Comment: Those variables are all coming from other places in the php script (i.e. global variables, function parameters). I've narrowed down the issue to the 7zip process, so I didn't bother cluttering up the post with the rest of the script.

Comment: May I suggest a "debug" option, before you run 7za make a copy of the file to a /tmp/ directory, then run 7za, at least if it fails, you know how the failed file looks like, because at the moment, I think you have a race condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looks like you have a race condition.  Try the debug option in the comments.